# How could this incompatible type assignment possible?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am developing some custom editor for VS2013. And I encountered the following function call:

[image]

How could a `SnapshotPoint` struct argument be passed to an `int` parameter?

The second overload of `Span` is:

```
Span.Span()
```

Comment: What type does the overloaded constructor of `Span` accept in its first argument?  Also could be an implicit conversion operator, perhaps.

Comment: @WordsLikeJared `Span.Span()`

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could show some context, for example what types you're talking about here and a link to the relevant documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `SnapshotPoint` can be [implicitly converted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.snapshotpoint.op_implicit.aspx) to an integer.

> Implicitly converts the snapshot point to an integer equal to the position of the snapshot point in the snapshot

```
public static implicit operator int (
  SnapshotPoint snapshotPoint
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Most likely because `SnapshotPoint` has an [implicit conversion to `int`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx).

Like this:

```
public static implicit operator int(SnapshotPoint s)
{
    return s.SomeProperty;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `SnapshotPoint` implements both a [custom addition operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.snapshotpoint.op_addition.aspx) (so `span.Start + offset` returns another `SnapshotPoint`) and an [implicit conversion to int](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.snapshotpoint.op_implicit.aspx).